# How can i use Word Sense Disambiguation with spanish?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm doing an udemy course (All the examples in English) but the problem is always when i start using Spanish, always there is a lack of libraries or compatibilities. I downloaded from https://www.datos.gov.co/Ciencia-Tecnolog-a-e-Innovaci-n/LAS-WordNet-una-WordNet-para-el-espa-ol-obtenida-c/8z8d-85m7 the data in CSV, but i'm trying to execute the following code but crashes with NoneType error, because of the description of the context, does anyone has any idea about how to deal with it? Thank you

```
import nltk
#nltk.download("omw")
from nltk.corpus import wordnet


for ss in wordnet.synsets("casco", lang="spa"):
    print(ss, ss.definition)


from nltk.wsd import lesk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

cntxt1 = lesk(word_tokenize("El casco antiguo de Barcelona es muy bonito"), "casco")
print(cntxt1, cntxt1..definition())
cntxt2 = lesk(word_tokenize("El casco nuevo que te has comprado para la motocicleta no me gusta"), "casco")
print(cntxt2, cntxt2.definition())
```

ERROR:

```
    print(cntxt1, cntxt1.definition())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'definition'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at [the source for the `lesk` function](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/wsd.html), and if it is not explicitly passed a `synsets` argument it creates one by calling `wordnet.synsets(ambiguous_word)`, but it doesn't pass a language option or anything.

If no synset is found for the word it just returns `None` hence the error you're getting.  You can explicitly pass a synset like:

```py
cntxt1 = lesk(word_tokenize("El casco antiguo de Barcelona es muy bonito"), 
              "casco", synsets=wordnet.synsets("casco", lang="spa"))
```

Comment: Yes i solved the error doing that at the end, but not the question is why should i repeat the word"casco" there? jeje Anyway you fixed it, thanks

Comment: I think it's a weakness in the API for this function.  I think for the second argument it should take either a word *or* an already instantiated synsnet for that word.  I would suggest [opening an issue for it](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/new) since you're right that the existing interface requires superfluous arguments in this case.